# CSS grid inside Flexbox suddenly breaks

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

So I've got .articleWrapper for post child items that scales just as I want it to scale. However placing this .articleWrapper inside another wrapper-element with dipslay: flex suddenly breaks .articleWrappers ability to scale horizontally after certain point.

There must be some flaw in my logic, but I can't find it.

Below is the code. If I remove display: flex and flex-wrap: wrap; the grid works fine. Also if I replace flex with block, it works fine. If I put display: flex; back in grid-content no longer stack.

```css
.siteWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.articleWrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(285px, 1fr));
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}

article {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="siteWrapper">
    <div class="articleWrapper">
        <article>
           <h1>Title</h1>
           <p>Para</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Para</p>
         </article>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Ah sorry. New to stackoverflow :). I was able to reproduce the problem with this amount of code now.

Comment: We can't so please add your HTML

Comment: HTML added and tried to find the bare minimum this time around.

Comment: Okay whoah. I did not know Stackoverflow can run my code in snippets too! That's neat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found one solution myself, but I still don't understand why it works.
Adding width: 100%; to .articleWrapper seems to have fixed the issue in this case.